# Call web api method inside ReactJS web worker with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using Web Worker with ReactJS (Context API schema) and facing with this problem.

My Web API and Context was designed as bellow:

**WebWorker.js**

```
export default class WebWorker {
  constructor(worker) {
    let code = worker.toString();
    code = code.substring(code.indexOf("{") + 1, code.lastIndexOf("}"));
    const blob = new Blob([code], { type: "application/javascript" });
    return new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
  }
}
```

And custom **AppWorker.js**

```
import { axios } from 'axios'
  export default function AppWorker(args) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    let onmessage = function (e) {
      if (e.data.action === "join_network") {
        axios.get('http://example.com/').then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }
    };
  }
```

On main component, inside **componentDidMount()** method

```
//App Component.js
import WebWorker from '../../core/Workers/WebWorker';
import AppWorker from '../../core/Workers/AppWorker';

componentDidMount() {
  //Start worker for stuff here
  const workerInstance = new WebWorker(AppWorker);
  workerInstance.addEventListener("message", e => {
    console.log(e.data);
  }, false);

  workerInstance.postMessage({
    action: "join_network"
  });
}
```

I've been told that we can call API method in Web worker, but when I ran the script, this error shown (see the attached link).

Anyone here get the problem ?

edit: add link: https://pastebin.com/9jRn25Ek
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJOuZ.jpg

Comment: You forgot to attach the link :)

Comment: Hi bro ,this is link: https://pastebin.com/9jRn25Ek

Comment: @HiếuTrần Did you find any solution ? I'm also facing same.

Comment: Same error for me despite following the suggestions: 
Uncaught ReferenceError: axios__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not defined
    at onmessage (ae4a52c1-59c1-4312-858f-4129025454b9:4)

Comment: I'm having the same error as @azsl1326 and cannot find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a late answer, but better late than never. You're not importing Axios properly, hence the reference error. You're attempting to import a single export from the Axios library that doesn't exist. In your `AppWorker.js` file, change the import to:

`import axios from 'axios'`

This will import the default export from the Axios library and you'll good to go.

Comment: Can you import axios from a CDN using `importScripts()`?

Comment: If not, the Fetch and XMLHttpRequest APIs [are available within web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers).

Comment: I don't think this is the root cause of the OP problem. I'm having the same issue and do not have incorrect imports. The problem seems to be tied to utilizing promises or async/await within the worker.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal case. Even if you import `axios` in `AppWorker` them have a different execute context.

In webworker executing `AppWorker` doesn't use `axios`.

Answer (score 0):

You can import cdn of axios package in Webworker

Using jsDelivr CDN:
self.importScripts('https://npmcdn.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js')

Using unpkg CDN:
self.importScripts('https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js')

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).